# Copy Files from one Linux server to another with Encryption

Tags: linux, files, encryption

When copying files from one Linux server to another, the files should be encrypted. The logs should maintain the record of files and their uploader's IP address. The problem with ftp is they send passwords in plain text but the plus point is that the logs are very descriptive and helpful. While scp logs only shows who logged in to the system. Since scp is encrypted, can there be a more descriptive.

Comment: Try rsync (rsync -avz -e ssh source dest....)

Comment: [FTPS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FTPS) maybe?

Comment: @HBrujin.. proper logs are not maintained.

Comment: Also,  we are having some connection troubles with FTPS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SCP is the most common way to do this.

RE logging activity.... You can change the loglevel directive in the sshd conf however since SCP is just an SSH connection, all you will likely see is the login itself.

I have found this for you however with details how to log SCP activity:

[Monitor file copies with SCP done via SSH](https://serverfault.com/questions/391743/monitor-file-copies-with-scp-done-via-ssh)

Alternatively, you could use rsync over ssh.

Answer (score 2):

[vsftpd](https://security.appspot.com/vsftpd.html) is an FTP server with extensive logging capability and supporting SSL encryption. It is available as a standard package in most Linux distributions.
If you set the configuration option `ssl_enable=yes` it will enforce SSL encryption for both login and data on all non-anonymous sessions by default.

Several FTP clients with SSL support are available, too, including [FileZilla](https://filezilla-project.org/) and [lftp](http://lftp.yar.ru/).